# Using Maven, how can I assemble several modules into one artifact?

Tags: maven-2

We have a mother-ship project with several modules:

```
foo
+ foo-core
+ foo-resource
+ foo-util
+ foo-whatever
```

I want to allow developers to include the core, resource, and util modules as dependencies (excluding the -whatever module).  I know that I can specify that they include each dependency, but it would be nice to allow for them to just specify something like

```
<artifactId>foo-sdk</artifactId>
```

And get everything that they need to develop a foo.  This has the added advantage that it gives us the power to add (or remove) what goes into the sdk.

It would be best if foo-sdk was not just a jar with the other jars jammed in it.  I'd rather it be a pom that simply points to the other artifacts.

I feel like I've seen this done before but can't find instructions to do it.  I checked out [Maven Assembly Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html) but it doesn't look like this is its intended use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group dependencies in a project with a packaging of type `pom`. From the Maven book:

> #### 3.6.1. Grouping Dependencies
>
> If you have a set of dependencies
>   which are logically grouped together.
>   You can create a project with pom
>   packaging that groups dependencies
>   together. For example, let's assume
>   that your application uses Hibernate,
>   a popular Object-Relational mapping
>   framework. Every project which uses
>   Hibernate might also have a dependency
>   on the Spring Framework and a MySQL
>   JDBC driver. Instead of having to
>   include these dependencies in every
>   project that uses Hibernate, Spring,
>   and MySQL you could create a special
>   POM that does nothing more than
>   declare a set of common dependencies.
>   You could create a project called
>   `persistence-deps` (short for
>   Persistence Dependencies), and have
>   every project that needs to do
>   persistence depend on this convenience
>   project:
>
> **Example 3.11. Consolidating Dependencies in a Single POM Project**
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook</groupId>
>   <artifactId>persistence-deps</artifactId>
>   <version>1.0</version>
>   <packaging>pom</packaging>
>   <dependencies>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>       <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
>       <version>${hibernateVersion}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
>       <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
>       <version>${hibernateAnnotationsVersion}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
>       <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
>       <version>${springVersion}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>mysql</groupId>
>       <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
>       <version>${mysqlVersion}</version>
>     </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>   <properties>
>     <mysqlVersion>(5.1,)</mysqlVersion>
>     <springVersion>(2.0.6,)</springVersion>
>     <hibernateVersion>3.2.5.ga</hibernateVersion>
>     <hibernateAnnotationsVersion>3.3.0.ga</hibernateAnnotationsVersion>
>   </properties>
> </project>
> ```
>
> If you create this project in a
>   directory named persistence-deps, all
>   you need to do is create this
>   `pom.xml` and run `mvn install`. Since
>   the packaging type is `pom`, this POM
>   is installed in your local repository.
>   You can now add this project as a
>   dependency and all of its dependencies
>   will be added as transitive
>   dependencies to your project. When you
>   declare a dependency on this
>   `persistence-deps` project, don't
>   forget to specify the dependency type
>   as `pom`.
>
> **Example 3.12. Declaring a Dependency on a POM**
>
> ```
> <project>
>   <description>This is a project requiring JDBC</description>
>   ...
>   <dependencies>
>     ...
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook</groupId>
>       <artifactId>persistence-deps</artifactId>
>       <version>1.0</version>
>       <type>pom</type>
>     </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
> </project>
> ```
>
> If you later decide to switch to a
>   different JDBC driver (for example,
>   JTDS), just replace the dependencies
>   in the persistence-deps project to use
>   net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds instead of
>   mysql:mysql-java-connector and update
>   the version number. All projects
>   depending on persistence-deps will use
>   JTDS if they decide to update to the
>   newer version. Consolidating related
>   dependencies is a good way to cut down
>   on the length of pom.xml files that
>   start having to depend on a large
>   number of dependencies. If you need to
>   share a large number of dependencies
>   between projects, you could also just
>   establish parent-child relationships
>   between projects and refactor all
>   common dependencies to the parent
>   project, but the disadvantage of the
>   parent-child approach is that a
>   project can have only one parent.
>   Sometimes it makes more sense to group
>   similar dependencies together and
>   reference a pom dependency. This way,
>   your project can reference as many of
>   these consolidated dependency POMs as
>   it needs. Note
>
> Maven uses the depth of a dependency
>   in the tree when resolving conflicts
>   using a nearest-wins approach. Using
>   the dependency grouping technique
>   above pushes those dependencies one
>   level down in the tree. Keep this in
>   mind when choosing between grouping in
>   a pom or using `dependencyManagement`
>   in a parent POM

Comment: "You can group dependencies in a project with a packaging of type pom" Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this just be another sub-module foo-sdk with packaging pom and dependencies on foo-{core,resource,util}?